# I do not know what an EOF error means and I want to know what version of Python various things support

Tags: python

I am very new to coding and would just like to know some basic things.

I learn code from CodeAcademy.com and I would like to know what version of python they teach. This is because when I copy some of the practice codes into say, Atom, I receive an EOFerror even after changing 'raw_input' to 'input'. Although, this same code that does not work in Atom works in Thonny.

I would like to know: What an EOFerror is, what version of Python Code Academy teaches, and what IDE I would use to practice what I learn from Code Academy.

Comment: Can you post a specific example of where you see this error? What is the exact code? When does the error occur? Is it when you run the program? Or is it when the user types in input?

Answer (score 0):

Codecademy teaches Python using Python 2.7.3. You can see what version they use by typing:

```
import sys
print sys.version()
```

You can download [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) or use IDLE, which comes with the default Python package as your IDE.

From the Python 2 [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html):

> **exception EOFError**
>
> > Raised when one of the built-in functions (input()
> >     or raw_input()) hits an end-of-file condition (EOF) without reading
> >     any data. (N.B.: the file.read() and file.readline() methods return an
> >     empty string when they hit EOF.)